# Online repository for .NET reusable controls

Tags: .net, code-reuse

Is there any online repository exist for .NET reusable controls?

**Edit**

I am asking this question because I have few reusable component with me, which I have developed, with source code. I don't want to write blog for each of them and even I don't want my developers friend, on internet, to get the DLL only with no source code.

Comment: may be something like user controls which has source code with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official WPF / WinForms web site control gallery:

http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/default.aspx

ASP.NET Control Gallery:

http://www.asp.net/Community/Control-gallery/

CodeProject has a search facility for sorting content about controls (note the left-hand nav bar):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/

CodePlex tends to house lots of .NET related things:

http://www.codeplex.com/

Namely the Silverlight / WP7 Control Toolkits, and perhaps a WPF toolkit.

Then there is, some many say, the grand-daddy of them all:

http://www.google.co.uk

(Apologies for the sarcasm, I just had to :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's NuGet package manager for visual studio. Other than that, you can browse online for OS projects hosted on sites like CodePlex, althought most of them are already integrated in NuGet.